# Booting Operating System from bootable secondary Hard disk via VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have attached a new bootable Hard Disk to my computer. I can boot to an operating system from each one.

When I boot into an Ubuntu system in one Hard Disk, is it possible to boot into the other Hard Disk from virtualbox so that I have both operating systems running at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. VirtualBox has a nice documentation on this that can be found on [this link](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) (Section 9.9, Advanced Storage Configuration).

It is for advanced users only so make sure you go through the documentation by VirtualBox thoroughly before attempting this since it could result to data loss / crashing of the host OS if not done correctly.